# What does <++> mean in vim (latex-suite), and how do I jump there?

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I am using *vim-latex-suite* and do not get how to jump to the `<++>` in expanded macros.

For example, when typing SSE in insert mode, I get:

```latex
/section{}<++>
```

What is the exact meaning of `<++>` and how do I move there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

That's a cursor placeholder, specific to the LaTeX suite. Sometimes there will be some text included. [This page](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html) explains more on the suite included macros.

Comment: Awwww, thx. I just went right into the subsections of the manual and overlooked the root-site for that section you pointed to. Thx! Shame on me. :P

Comment: No worries @NilsHaldenwang , the problem with good documentation is that sometimes it's just too much documentation to read :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's a placeholder for insertion

If my memory serves me right, you can use `ctrl-J` to move there.

It's a way to save key-presses when moving around.