# What does <++> mean in gvim?

Tags: vim, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does <++> mean in vim (latex-suite), and how do I jump there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344069/what-does-mean-in-vim-latex-suite-and-how-do-i-jump-there)

My default editor is vim but I shifted to gvim for the latex suite. Whenever I type `$$` in quick succession it adds a `<++>` after the second `$` symbol. What does that mean and how do i disable that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Vim-Latex FAQ](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=faq&title=FAQ#faq-placeholders):

> **Q: What are those annoying «» characters whenever I invoke a
>   mapping?**
>
> Those are called placeholders and when you get used to them, they
>   will prove invaluable. They are essentially markers left in the text
>   file to tell latex-suite where the next point of interest is. This
>   lets you directly go to the next placeholder with a single key-press.
>   Consider a working example. Pressing EFI will insert the following
>   micro template:

```latex
 \begin{figure}[h] 
     \centerline{\psfig{figure=«eps file»}}
     \caption{«caption text»} 
     \label{fig:«label»}
  \end{figure}«»
```

> The text «eps file» will be selected and vim will be left in
>   select-mode so that the user can continue typing straight away. After
>   having typed in the file name, she can press Control-J (while still in
>   insert-mode). This will take her directly to the next "place-holder".
>   i.e, «caption text» will be visually selected with vim in select
>   mode again for typing in the caption. This saves on a lot of key
>   presses.
>
> If you still do not feel like using placeholders, include `let g:Imap_UsePlaceHolders = 0`
>   in your `.vimrc`.